javafx not working on raspberry 64 bit - Unable to open DISPLAY
I want to move from 32 to 64bit Raspbian lite without desktop (because of the new JDK versions > 19 which are only available for 64 bit linux arm).
I have a small javafx app I developed when javafx was bundled together with the JDK (1.8) ages ago.
But now I realize that I can't get it working as it is with the aarch64 gluon SDKs.
I minimized my code to be simply reproducible by this class:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class FxHelloWorldApp  extends Application{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100);");

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        
        stage.show();
        
    }
}

You can download it compiled here: https://upload.disroot.org/r/ZFHLAoJJ#nYvlQuHKacBACwhWAP5Sf3kxzNweuy7o0WBkvpStBFo=
i can launch the compiled class very simple on an actual 32 bit rasbian with the arm32 version of the SDK
java  -cp . --module-path javafx/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls FxHelloWorldApp

but when i run this on the 64 bit rasbian with the aarch64 version of the SDK i get
Unable to open DISPLAY

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1091)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:202)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:200)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)

On both versions of Raspbian, I use the default jdk17-jre which I installed with
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre

I'm surprised that the aarch64 version is not working like the arm32 one.
Does anyone has a tip how to get it working?
Update:
I tried the monocle-jar from https://github.com/TestFX/Monocle
java -Djava.library.path=javafx-sdk-23/lib/  -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dmonocle.platform=Headless -Dprism.order=sw -cp openjfx-monocle-21.0.2.jar:. --module-path javafx-sdk-23/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.logging=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx=ALL-UNNAMED FxHelloWorldApp

now there is no error but also no rendering

Please [edit] your question to include this detail.

the error "Unable to open DISPLAY" has nothing to do with JavaFX and/or programming.  I think you need to ask here: https://superuser.com/search?q=Unable+to+open+DISPLAY or here: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=unable+to+open+display

i think gluon could help, because its confusing that it works on the nowadays unsupported arm32 platform and not on the supported arm64 one

by the way - it works well in the desktop version of the same raspbian

It works on a desktop version, because there is a display manager running.  If a display manager is not running, you will get a "Unable to open DISPPLAY".

but how is it working in the  arm32 non desktop version? i thought java fx renders into the framebuffer and needs no window manager - this was really cool and resource-saving

in the gluon docs https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_install_javafx_for_64_bits they write "Browse for Linux OS, aarch64 architecture and Monocle SDK type" but there is no monocle sdk type


are you talking to yourself?   2) no download of Monocle SDK on linux x64

